# Different inference result from the same model with different saving format .pb and .ckpt

Tags: python, tensorflow

I saved the trained model into .ckpt files and then convert the .ckpt files to .pb file. And finally restored the model from both .ckpt and .pb file to infer. Curiously I got slightly different results from .ckpt and .pb file. In addition, I got slightly different results every time running the codes.

```
# coding: utf-8

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"


def restore_pb(img_data, pb_file_path=None):
    '''restore model from .pb to infer
    '''
    if not pb_file_path:
        pb_file_path = "test/inceptionV3_0.pb"
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile(pb_file_path, "rb") as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            return_elems = ['tower_0/InceptionV3/predictions/Softmax:0']
            predictions = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, return_elements=return_elems)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            # print(tf.contrib.graph_editor.get_tensors(tf.get_default_graph()))
            # for node in sess.graph.node:
            #     print(node.name)
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            image = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/x:0')
            #label = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('y:0')

            predictions = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={image: img_data})
            print('pb predictions:', predictions[0])
```

```
def restore_ckpt(img_data):
    '''restore model from .ckpt to infer
    '''
    cpkt_meta = 'test/inception_mom1to2_rand5.ckpt-0.meta'
    ckpt = 'test/inception_mom1to2_rand5.ckpt-0'
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        graph = tf.Graph()
        config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
        with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(cpkt_meta)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt)
            # print(tf.contrib.graph_editor.get_tensors(tf.get_default_graph()))
            image = graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
            preds = graph.get_tensor_by_name('tower_0/InceptionV3/predictions/Softmax:0')
            predictions = sess.run(preds, feed_dict={image: img_data})
            print('ckpt predictions:', predictions)
```

```
def ckpt2pb():
    '''convert .ckpt to .pb file
    '''
    # some path
    output_nodes = ['tower_0/InceptionV3/predictions/Softmax']
    cpkt_meta = 'test/inception_mom1to2_rand5.ckpt-0.meta'
    ckpt = 'test/inception_mom1to2_rand5.ckpt-0'
    pb_file_path = 'test/inceptionV3_ckpt2pb.pb'

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        graph = tf.Graph()
        config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)

        with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
            # restored model from ckpt
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(cpkt_meta)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt)

            # save freeze graph into .pb file
            graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
            constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph_def, output_nodes)
            with tf.gfile.FastGFile(pb_file_path, mode='wb') as f:
                f.write(constant_graph.SerializeToString())
```

```
img_data = cv2.imread('tumor_009_19327_175114_0.jpeg')
img_data = cv2.cvtColor(img_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_data = (np.array(img_data).astype(np.float32)) / 256.0
img_data = np.reshape(img_data, [-1, 256, 256, 3])

restore_pb(img_data)
restore_ckpt(img_data)
ckpt2pb()
restore_pb(img_data, pb_file_path='test/inceptionV3_ckpt2pb.pb')
```

Results:

```
2019-05-10 16:56:42.793083: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-05-10 16:56:44.553334: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla P40 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.531
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 22.38GiB freeMemory: 22.21GiB
2019-05-10 16:56:44.553413: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-05-10 16:56:44.804127: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-05-10 16:56:44.804196: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2019-05-10 16:56:44.804204: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2019-05-10 16:56:44.804687: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21557 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P40, pcibus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
pb predictions: [[0.31244308 0.6875569 ]]
2019-05-10 16:56:47.791268: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-05-10 16:56:47.791313: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-05-10 16:56:47.791321: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2019-05-10 16:56:47.791326: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2019-05-10 16:56:47.791480: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21557 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P40, pcibus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
ckpt predictions: [[0.27373236 0.7262676 ]]
2019-05-10 16:56:52.778329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-05-10 16:56:52.778398: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-05-10 16:56:52.778406: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2019-05-10 16:56:52.778414: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2019-05-10 16:56:52.778624: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21557 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P40, pcibus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Converted 190 variables to const ops.
2019-05-10 16:56:58.946692: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-05-10 16:56:58.946815: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-05-10 16:56:58.946827: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2019-05-10 16:56:58.946834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2019-05-10 16:56:58.947005: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21557 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P40, pcibus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
pb predictions: [[0.28257495 0.71742505]]
```

It can be seen the results:

```
pb predictions: [[0.31244308 0.6875569 ]] # this model gerated from last running

ckpt predictions: [[0.27373236 0.7262676 ]]

pb predictions: [[0.28257495 0.71742505]]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect saving floating point numbers may dro some precision, so you might expect small differences from that when saved in one format. No idea on the difference between these two formats though.

Comment: But I think the droped precision would not result in such large difference. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I have analogous question. Do you get conclusion about it?<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309033/different-inference-result-when-use-the-same-ckpt-to-export-model